# AJAX Post response data does not write to DOM with $('input').val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have some bizarre behavior going on with this AJAX response.

On the PHP page, I have:

```
echo $items = $_POST["items"];
```

And my ajax function:

```
  $j('.share-pdf').on('click', function () {
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.addClass('loading');

    var pullsheetName = "pullsheet-backbone",
        pullsheet = localStorage.getItem(pullsheetName);

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        data: {
            items: pullsheet
        },
        url: '/create-pdf?store=true',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $body.removeClass('loading');
            $('#share-url input').val(data).select();
            $('#share-url').addClass('shared')
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

While `alert(data)` alerts the data that has been posted, nothing appears in the input, as `$('#share-url input').val(data).select();` is supposed to do.

What am I doing wrong here and why isn't `val()` writing the data correctly to the specified input?

Comment: Without the HTML it might be hard to spot the error.

Comment: did you successfully select the input?

Comment: what is `$body = $('body');`
What are you selecting id or class??

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan - that form selects the body tag/element - so neither of your options.

Answer (score 1):

Try a little colon:

```
$('#share-url:input').val(data).select();
```

Your

```
$('#share-url input').val(data).select();
```

means: in jQuery find inputs inside of such as:

```
 $('#share-url').find('input').val(data).select();
```

Which is an ancestor/descendant form of a selector re: `$('div span')` - find spans in divs

Comment: NOTE: I would strongly suggest `$('input#share-url')` or simply `$('#share-url')` for the selector for speed, preference on the latter IF you do not need to ensure the input type.

Comment: IF this does not answer, then "data" is not simple text but some more complex type and `data.item` or something similar is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you'll need to use the following instead:

```
$('#share-url input').val(function(){ 
    return data[$(this).attr('name')]; 
}).select();
```

This is assuming that `data` is a javascript object that contains the data, rather than just a string of your data. My assumption might be wrong. However, without further information, it's hard to figure out where the problem is.